# Determine Who did What from Transaction logs

Tags: sql-server

We received full backup and transaction logs files from a third party, which is used to restore our local SQL Server instance.

We are trying to know who did what from these files. I searched online and my query looks like:

The problem is Transaction SID column is always empty. Is there any way to fix this?

```
SELECT  so.*, Operation, [Transaction SID],SUSER_NAME([Transaction SID]) AS [LoginName]
FROM fn_dump_dblog(NULL,NULL,'DISK',1
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak0'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak1'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak2'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak3'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak4'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak5'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak6'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak7'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak8'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak9'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak10'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak11'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak12'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak13'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak14'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak15'
,'C:\yardi_tran\extract\201911130900.bak16'
,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,   NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,   NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,   NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,   NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) blog
INNER JOIN
sys.partitions sp ON blog.PartitionId=sp.partition_id
INNER JOIN
sys.objects so ON so.object_id = sp.object_id
WHERE blog.Operation ='LOP_DELETE_ROWS'
AND so.type_desc='USER_TABLE'
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "who did what"?  Which user / login executed each statement?  Also, keep in mind that even if you do get a SID it will be the SID from the original server which is not going to be the same as the SID on the new server unless you've taken measures to copy users between the servers.

Comment: Yes, We need to know who runs which query.

Comment: That's not something that the transaction log is used for.  If you need to do that you need to run a trace on the original server, or use extended events.